# Lightning expression And && behaving wierdly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I was writing some code in aura and came across this scenario which I feel is more like a bug.

***and*** function with more than 2 parameters gives incorrect values.

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:attribute name="first" type="Boolean" default="true"></aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute name="second" type="Boolean" default="true"></aura:attribute>

    <aura:attribute name="third" type="Boolean" default="false"></aura:attribute>

    Print Answer: {!and(v.first,v.second,v.third)}
</aura:application>
```

And to my surprise output was

> Print Answer: true

I tried it in W18 and Spring 18, Still same output.
The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm) for logical expression doesnt provide an answer, I belive the behavior should be consistent. The same formula works fine with database formula fields.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox I coudn't find it while searching here. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yeah. I know they'll probably fix it some day, but no time line yet.

Comment: I added a comment to the original answer as well. You can use also use `&amp;&amp;` which is `&&` escaped for XML.